# finding the union and intercept of (x,y)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to calculate $\cup\{(x,y)|y^n\leq x\}$ and $\cap\{(x,y)|y^n\leq x\}$ for all positive integers n.

I'm fairly new to set theory and I have absolutely no idea how to proceed with this. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: For a set $S$ the union  $\cup S$ is the set of MEMBERS OF MEMBERS of $S$. The members of your set are ordered pairs. There is more than one preferred definition  in set theory of  what an ordered pair is.